# What better than to

Tags: ellipsis, comparison

> (It is so easy to pick up fruits at the market when they are plentiful and so fresh during their seasonal time.)
>
> 1. So **what better** than to turn them into a lovely jam, jelly, or even a marmalade to bring that summer sunshine onto the table in the middle of winter.
>    (https://www.thespruceeats.com/difference-between-jelly-jam-and-marmalade-435612)

I can understand the meaning, but I want to know if "**what" and "better"** are in the same noun phrase (interpretation 1a) or in two different constituents (interpretation 1b).

**1a.** what better (way) (is there)than to turn them into a...
**1b**. what (is) better than to turn them into a...

This question has been bothering me for a while. Thanks in advance if you would help.

Comment: As a native BrE speaker I would say 1b is the correct interpretation creating a rhetorical question. If all else fails with interpreting English then apply Occam's Razor - pick the simplest version.

Comment: I concur with @PeterJennings; I'm an AmE native and 1b seems like it's the closest to the intended meaning. I read this as an elision of the verm *can*: "So what better than to turn them into a lovely jam"="so what **could** be better than to turn them into a lovely jam"="could there be anything better than to turn them into a lovely jam?"